# Assign firestore value to variable using read function in Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm reading data from a firestore database in the function below, and I want to assign specific data values to variables in my structure. For example I have the variable 'currentRating' that I want to equal data.currentRating. How would I call the data value in my variable?

```
    private func listenDocument() {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("RatingInformation").document("Brittain")
            .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
              guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
              }
              guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
              }
              print("Current data: \(data)")
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get data by key-value concept:

```
// Add callback using closure
func fetchRatingInfomation(documentPath: String, completion: ([String: Any]?) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore()
        .collection("RatingInformation")
        .document(documentPath)
        .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
            guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            guard let jsonData = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was NULL.") //
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            print("Current data: \(jsonData)")
            completion(jsonData)
        }
    }
}

// Calling inside your class body
fetchRatingInfomation(documentPath: "Brittain") {[weak self] jsonData in
    guard let _jsonData = jsonData else { return }
    print(_jsonData["currentRating"]) // Here is how you get value of document's attribute
}
```

Comment: How would I pull jsonData["currentRating"] to a private variable in the View structure which has this function within it?

Comment: @FrancescaD Pls check my answer again. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the document's `get` function.

```
private func listenDocument() {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("RatingInformation").document("Brittain").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let doc = snapshot else {
            if let error = error {
                print("error", error)
            }
            return
        }
        guard doc.exists else {
            print("no document")
            return
        }
        if let currentRating = doc.get("currentRating") as? Int {
            someExistingStruct.currentRating = currentRating
        }
        if let usualRating = doc.get("usualRating") as? Int {
            someExistingStruct.usualRating = usualRating
        }
        if let someTitle = doc.get("someTitle") as? String {
            someExistingStruct.someTitle = someTitle
        }
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I structure this for multiple variables. For instance, currentRating and usualRating which are both different values in the same Firestore document

Comment: @FrancescaD depends on how you want the logic to flow. Do you only want to populate this object if all the properties in the document exist or will you populate the object with whatever properties are available? And do you want to assign default values if the property is `nil` or missing or just ignore them altogether?

Comment: the object will be updated with all the properties since I am writing the properties to the database from user inputs and then reading them back to the variables so that they are updated after each user input.